# Why does this 3-line gfortran code throw a segmentation fault?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This simple 3-line gfortran code generates a "Program received signal SIGSEGV:  Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference" at the OPEN statement.  What am I doing wrong?

I've turned off (and back on) the "Run-time checks" compiler switches:  -fcheck= all and -fcheck=bounds.  No improvement from doing this.  Other compile switches are off.  I also tried defining the name of the file in the OPEN statement in a character variable.  Also, no improvement.  Also tried replacing single quotes with double quotes.  No help.

```
  PROGRAM INTSFRACM_271
  OPEN(7,IOSTAT=IOS,FILE='namlist.int',STATUS='OLD')
  END
```

This is the entire program.

See above.

Comment: What version of gfortran are you using?

Comment: GNU Fortran (tdm-1) 5.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, very unfortunately, GFortran v5.1.0 is [bugged](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/487/) such that valid files will cause a segfault when `OPEN`ed.  Try updating to v5.2 or higher.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much, Clayton.  I updated to gfortran 8.1, and that fixed it.  5.1 is the default version distributed with Code Blocks, I believe.  Nasty!

Comment: @dvdman: welcome to stack overflow. If you find this answers your question, then please select it as the "accepted answer" -- that's the best way to say thanks here.